# Axios + Typescript: how to pass a param of type "ResponseType"?

Tags: typescript, axios

Axios defines `ResponseType` as

```
export type ResponseType = 
  | 'arraybuffer' 
  | 'blob' 
  | 'document' 
  | 'json' 
  | 'text' 
  | 'stream'
```

I'm trying to pass a configuration to axios.post

```
const config = {
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Host': HOST_HEADER,
        },
        responseType: 'json'
 }

 const data_to_post = { .... omitted ... }

 return axios.post(HOST, data_to_post, config)
```

**Problem**: typescript linter warn me saying the type string cannot be assigned to type ResponseType.

**Also tried:** Of course I cannot use the syntax

```
 responseType: ResponseType.json
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript will infer `config` to be of type

```
{
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': string;
        'Content-Type': string;
        'Host-Header': string;
    };
    responseType: string;
}
```

Typescript does not know that you are trying to create a config object for Axios. You can explicitly type the entire object as `AxiosRequestConfig`, or you could explicitly type `responseType: 'json'` to be of type `ResponseType`.

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host-Header': 'dsa',
  },
  responseType: 'json'
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed using explicit casting

```
responseType: <ResponseType> 'json'
```